# Make gem executable use a specific dependent gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm creating a gem which depends on a specific version of another gem.

```
  spec.add_dependency "some_gem", "1.0.0"
```

Inside my gem, I have an executable.  When someone installs my gem, the dependent gem is installed as expected, and the executable works as expected.

`some_gem` installs its own executable and my gem calls that executable with some specific options.

However, if the user installs a newer version of `some_gem` on their machine, my executable starts using the newer version.  How do I restrict my executable to use the executable of the version of the gem that my gemspec defines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by calling the dependent gem's executable underscores:

```
some_gem_exectuable _1.0.0_
```